# Magento Transaction E-Mails Not Working (admin)

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I'd like to receive e-mails when someone buys something on my Magento website. I've added my e-mail to be 'BCC' in the sales e-mail section but nothing is received. Customers however do receive e-mails after making a purchase. Can anyone point me towards a troubleshoot process for this? I don't understand why customers are receiving the e-mails but as the store admin I am not.

Thank you very much

Comment: First thing coming to mind is emails ending up in the spam folder. Did you try another email address? Next to that check the Apache logs for errors, Magento logs and the servers email send log to check if emails are actually added tot the mail que

Comment: See also http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105741/order-emails-only-sent-to-customer-not-to-admin

Answer (score 0):

The cron heartbeat was the issue as it was not automated. I added the automation at server level under 'Scheduled Task' in Plesk Control Panel by providing the path to cron.php in the Magento directory and setting this to be run every 10 minutes.