# Order emails only sent to customer not to admin

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

There should be default feature in magento that would send email to admin as well about the order placement. I have cron setup and working, customer receiving email about order placement, but the admin doesn't get email.

I found that the exact copy customer receives can be send to multiple email addresses(via `configuration / sales emais / order /Send Order Email Copy To`), but there should be other email that will be send to admin. How it gets active or how to configure or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such e-mail that you are looking for.

I just had a look at the e-mail templates folder to prove this (see `app/locale/en_US/template/email`) but neither did I hear or see about such a version of an order e-mail that is sent to an admin before nor did I find one in this folder.

Comment: Ok, so there isn't this functionality that notifies admin via email that Jane doe has places an order. ? the admin needs to see from orders section by logging in only. no other pre-built notifying options ? thank you

Comment: No, you can just set up the copy of the order e-mail, as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

You need to send separate email to admin because BCC is buggy.
 Try below step :

> configuration->sales emais->order -> Send Order Email Copy Method = via seperate Mail

You can also consider the below mentioned point:
First of all, Magento 1.9+ relies completely on cron jobs to send transactional emails. If you didn’t have cron jobs set up properly before, you are going to have to do it now.

First of all make sure you have set up cron tasks in the Magento admin under System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron. The default settings are:

Generate Schedules Every 15 Schedule Ahead for 20 Missed if Not Run Within 15 History Cleanup Every 10 Success History Lifetime 60 Failure History Lifetime 600

There are people suggesting these settings should be changed, but since they can’t seem to agree on the best combination, I’d rather leave it as it is.

You then need to go into your hosting control panel and set up cron jobs.